# Java Regex to see if a String contains %s, %d, %n

Tags: java, regex, format

**S**o I'm writing my own variation of the `toString()` method and basically when you call the method you pass in a string and then an argument `toString(Object... args)`. Like so

```
this.toString("%8s", this.log, "%n%s %s", this.theMap, "%s", this.countIterator());
```

And from that I use the following code to see if the argument passed in is a regular String or a format String.

```
if(args[i].getClass().getName() == "java.lang.String") {
  if(args[i].toString().contains("%\\-?[1-9]s?*")) {

    format = args[i].toString();

  } else {

    s += args[i].toString();

  }
}
```

The `args[i].toString().contains("%\\-?[1-9]s?*")` regex isn't working, however when I use 
`args[i].toString().matches("%\\-?[1-9]s?*")` it works but only for instances of a String with `%s` or `%9s` not for instances with `%s %9s` or `%s%s %s`. And it also works when I swap the `s` in the regex with a `d` or `n`.

I know your asking why reinvent the wheel, just use `String.format()`, and I should it's just that I've got this on my mind and can't do anything else until I solve it.

I also tried copying and pasting the `java.util.Formatter` class'
`"%(\\d+\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])"` regex but it did the same as above and only worked for `%s` or `%9s`.

I also noticed in the Formatter class that the developers used an instance of the Matcher class with an instance of the Patern class and used a for loop to run through a String and match each instance of the pattern and stored it into an ArrayList. I don't really want to do that, I just want to see if the String argument has one instance of `%n` or `%s` or `%d` and from that store it in a String that will be used later in cobination with `String.format(format, argument);`.

So if anyone could help me that would be awesome!
Thank you for reading this far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(%[0-9]*(s|d|n))");
System.out.println("match: " + p.matcher(str).find());
```

you can store the pattern as a global or static variable and reuse it when you need.